# What is the best way to use one image for multiple ImageViews

Tags: java, android, algorithm, image, android-imageview

I have one image, but I want to work with multiple (from 1 to 8) ImageViews at the same time on screen. And the only conclusion I came to is to create 8 the same ImageViews with different ids.

Im my activity, it looks like this:

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/object0"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="107dp"
  android:visibility="invisible"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"/>
```

Then this:

```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/object1"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="107dp"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"/>
```

and so on ... (other 6 ImageViews)

In my code, I have an array of these objects. Then in a loop, I go through them and set correct object views. (I do it to manipulate them in a future.)

In my java activity code, I use this awful method to set views:

```
    private void setObjView(Object obj, int num) {
    if      (num == 0)
        obj.object_view = findViewById(R.id.object0);
    else if (num == 1)
        obj.object_view = findViewById(R.id.object1);
    else if (num == 2)
        obj.object_view = findViewById(R.id.object2);
// and so on...
}
```

So, are there any better ways to use one image for multiple ImageViews on the screen in the same moment?

Comment: use reyclerView for this

Comment: @Amitpandey thanks for your recommendation! I will research this tool.